# I'm unable to center an image inside a div after being loaded with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm loading images dynamically with jquery and can't seem to center them inside the div.  My HTML looks like this:

```
<div style="width:100%;border: solid 1px #ff0000;">
    <img id="current_photo" src="" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;max-width:97%;"/>
</div>
```

The jQuery call looks like this:

```
    $("#current_photo").attr('src', img_url);
    //$('#current_photo').css({'margin-right':'auto','margin-left':'auto'});
```

I'm assuming I need to apply the CSS after the image has loaded but this doesn't seem to work either.

No matter what I try the images are always left justified.  Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: These things are easier to debug on a live site or at lease a minimized version (http://jsfiddle.net/). 

You could have some other CSS influencing your image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add "text-align:center;" to your containing div.
Also no need for the auto margins.

Comment: I could swear I tried this earlier, but plugging it again worked fine. thanks!

Comment: Also, Paul, you could try coding the src directly into the HTML. Helps to break the problem down and figure out whether it's jQuery or CSS that's not working as anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in js, give this function a try after you load your img.

```
setToCenterOfParent($("#current_photo"), $("#current_photo").parent());

function setToCenterOfParent( obj, parentObj ) {
    var height = $( obj ).height();
    var width = $( obj ).width();
    if ( parentObj == window ) {
        $( obj ).css( 'top', ( $( parentObj ).height() / 2 ) - ( height / 2 ) );
        $( obj ).css( 'left', ( $( parentObj ).width() / 2 ) - ( width / 2 ) );
    }
    else {
        $( obj ).css( 'top', ( $( parentObj ).height() / 2 ) - ( height / 2 ) + $( parentObj ).position().top );
        $( obj ).css( 'left', ( $( parentObj ).width() / 2 ) - ( width / 2 ) + $( parentObj ).position().left );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to work by adding this style to your `img`:

```
display: block;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Zsq8Q/3/

The fact that you are setting the `src` dynamically is not the problem here, it is that an `img` element is not a block element by default so the margin setting doesn't work unless you *make* it a block.

Answer (score 0):

text-align property in the container will solve the problem :

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:100%;border: solid 1px #ff0000;">
    <img id="current_photo" src="" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;  max-width:97%;"/>
</div>
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zsq8Q/4/