# Center HTML element loaded with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My plan was the following:
Create a simple static website with some pictures, that are loaded based on browser-width(because mobile users don't need huge pictures loaded).
I tried the suggestions I found there:
[I'm unable to center an image inside a div after being loaded with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617873/im-unable-to-center-an-image-inside-a-div-after-being-loaded-with-jquery)
But it seems it doesn't work out for me. I tried the answers there, but it didn't help.
I even tried to change the properties afterwards with this:

```
$('.headerImg').css('margin','auto');
```

And several of the ideas in the link in it too. But it seems to ignore the center positioning. The image for testing purposes is displayed correctly, according to the width of the screen and I don't have multiple definitions for it in my css file. If anyone has a clue, I would truly appreciate it...

My code:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>broken</title>
        <!--styling-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="/styling/" href="styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <!-- Scripts-->
        <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/constants.js"></script>
        <!-- fetch and store screen sizes-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            localStorage.setItem("windowWith", screen.width);
            localStorage.setItem("windowHeight", screen.height);
            localStorage.setItem("imageSize", getImageSize());
        </script>

        <!--Header-->
        <div class="header">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var path = "media/img/header_" + localStorage.getItem("imageSize") + ".jpg";
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.headerImg').attr("src", path);
            });
            </script>
            <img class="headerImg"></img>
            <br>
            <div class)"menuItems"></div>
        </div>
        <!--Middle-->
        <div class="middle"></div>
        <!--Footer-->
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the needed *.js file for the calculation which picture is picked:

```
//const enum to define where 
var width = {
    large:1280,
    medium:800,
    small:460,
    xsmall:330
};

//sets the size for the header image
function getImageSize(){
    var size = "";
    var screenWidth = localStorage.getItem("windowWith");
    if(screenWidth >  width.medium){
        console.log("loading large picture");
        size = "large";
    }
    else if(screenWidth <= width.medium && screenWidth > width.small){
        console.log("loading medium picture");
        size = "medium";
    }
    else if(screenWidth <= width.small && screenWidth > width.xsmall){
        console.log("loading small picture");
        size = "small";
    }
    else if(screenWidth < width.small){
        console.log("loading xsmall picture");
        size = "xsmall";
    }
    if(size == ""){
        size = "xsmall";
        console.log("Error - screen size not found - loading xsmall header");
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: you want to center it horizontally then `display:inline-block; margin:0 auto;` for your image, and `text-align:center;` for parent should do the work. Did you try it? and there is an error in your html syntax at `<div class)"menuItems"></div>`, i hope you already noticed that

Comment: Here's a [link](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/) which does not solve your problem, but its a better way around than using jquery to dynamically set different images on different widths :

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error - but the stylings didn't solve it. They were mentioned in the (linked) question too. And I maybe should mention that I always view the site without cache. @ValentinoPereira: it looks pretty cool, but it isn't supported by M$:Edge and IE...so I have to use an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image tag  is inline element, which can not be centered with "margin: 0 auto;"

Make image "display: block;"

Your css should be like this:

```
    .headerImg {
    display: block;
    margin:  0 auto; 
}
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work out for me. I have no clue why it doesn't work. I refresh the page without caching, tried incognito mode and restarted my local XAMPP(Apache) in case anything got buffered...

Comment: Forgot to set css width to the image. You have to set it with js.

Comment: Or the better solution. Do not add any styles to image, just wrap it in div <div style="text-align: center; "><img class="headerImg"></div>

Comment: Thanks a ton! It worked. Thank you for taking your time in helping me :)